# Non Modal, Draggable, Jquery Popup

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, draggable, colorbox

I am in need of a non-modal, draggable popup that can display external webpages, preferably jquery or bootstrap.

I have found a plugin for colourbox that makes it draggable however it is still modal.

Does anyone have any ideas on how t achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

A simple plugin would be jQueryUI with the [Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). You could use a DIV with an IFRAME inside to open external webpages.

Another one but unfortunately a commercial one is the [Window](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/index) in KendoUI from Telerik